# Cause of Crash during Windows App Certification Kit test for Windows Universal app?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, winjs, windows-10-universal

I got the following error reported when I performed a Windows App Certification Kit Test. How do I go about figuring out what is the cause?

**Error Found: The crashes and hangs test detected the following errors:
Application XYZ was detected by Windows Error Reporting and experienced a crash or hang.**

I looked at the application reports generated in the Event Viewer, but it doesn't seem to indicate what is the cause. Is there a way to figure out the cause looking at these reports?

Answer (score 1):

This particular test in the Appcert Kit just monitors whether your application crashed at some point during testing.  The Appcert Kit tests follow a fairly common pattern for interacting with the app: Launch, Suspend, Terminate.  Its possible the app is crashing in anyone of these routines.  Best bet to understand what's happening is to try debugging the application while its being tested.  The reason for failure is going to be specific to your application, so perhaps start by getting it under a debugger and trying to catch the crash realtime, as the event logs aren't going to provide sufficient information.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441472.aspx

Thanks